# Blink not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, blink

I am using `blink` in my application to display error message. The problem is that it's working in Firefox but not in Chrome. I don't know what the problem is. How can I make it to work in Chrome?

Comment: It has been deprecated in Chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add following code to your css file,

```
blink {
-webkit-animation-name: blink; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0,0,0,1.0);
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it was specifically a question for Chrome, so the answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

```css
blink, .blink {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
    -o-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
    animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink { 67% { opacity: 0 }}
@-moz-keyframes blink {  67% { opacity: 0 }}
@-o-keyframes blink {  67% { opacity: 0 }}
@keyframes blink {  67% { opacity: 0 }}
```

Comment: This code will work for crome as well as firefox IE also just add <blink class="blink">Your text</blink>

Answer (score 5):

It is deprecated so you might try to do it with javascript. Here is an example I made out of jquery for you: http://jsfiddle.net/FPsdy/ It is very simple:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('.blink').toggle();
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 4):

Blink is deprecated, and you should not use it.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/blink

Comment: It is not deprecated, it has never been part of any standard. What is deprecated is `text-decoration: blink` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: Boo... if nothing else it was good for jokes. Great for 404 pages and stuff. "404 Error - You've found a page from 1998 you should not be here"

Comment: Would be better suited to a question entitled "Is Blink deprecated, and should I use it?"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines of code to your css file.

```
blink {
   -webkit-animation-name: blink; 
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic- 
    bezierr(1.0,0,0,1.0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  }
```

This is because many browsers doesn't support few css functions. You should try updating your chrome browser.

Answer (score -1):

Only need to import is a jquery.min.js file to use this code.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $('.blink').css("opacity","0.5");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.blink').css("opacity","1");
    },750);
}, 1500);
```

Comment: -1. This is doable without jQuery. You can use CSS animations, too. Using JavaScript for something that can, and should be done in CSS is a pet peeve of mine.