# How to make text blink on website?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and I want a hyperlink on the page to blink. It doens't matter how fast it does, only not too slow. It would also be cool if I could make it blink in different colors.

I have tried using text-decoration:blink; in css, but that didn't work.

I've added this to the css-file, but now what?:

```
blink {
-webkit-animation-name: blink; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0,0,0,1.0);
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Please don't...

Comment: You shouldn't make a hyperlink blink on a website.

Comment: The 1990s called and do **NOT** want their `<blink>` back. In fact, the 1990s offered up a bazillion dollars to keep the tag away.

Comment: Use Comic Sans please. `<marquee>` is still cool, right guys??

Comment: Please search for answer before you post a question. I'm sure it's not that difficult. here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery

Comment: Please try some animation with css3 or jquery instead.

Comment: :( <blink> is deprecated (firefox 23). This is for a reason. It is so annoying it is scary

Comment: Comic Sans and marquee already in place. I only need blink now.

Comment: `-webkit` is a vendor prefix for `webkit` based browsers, so you'll need the other vendor prefixes if you want it to work in other browsers that support `CSS3 Animation`

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Seems like a legit question. We're not here to judge from a UX-standpoint. +1 for curiosity

Comment: Downvotes are for being lazy.  It took all of 2 seconds to find the answer using SO search (`[css] blink`).

Comment: I seriously hope the website being linked to is a joke

Comment: wow
much effects
so creativity
very amaze
such skill
wow

Comment: I don't always make text blink with CSS, but when I do - I don't.

Comment: I'm using this as an alternate to a spinner, which looks very cool. So fk y'all

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with CSS animations.

```
a {   
  animation-duration: 400ms;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

You can also extend it to change colors. With something like:

```
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    color: pink;
  }

  25% {
    color: green;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    color: blue;
  }

  75% {
   opacity: 0;
   color: orange;
 }

 100% {
   opacity: 1;
   color: pink;
 }
}
```

Make sure to add vendor prefixes

Demo: http://codepen.io/pstenstrm/pen/yKJoe

#### Update

To remove the fading effect you can do:

```
b {
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-name: tgle;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes tgle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  99.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

This is also a useful trick when animating image-sprites

Comment: Sweet! Any way to remove that fading effect?

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you can remove the fading effect

Answer (score 4):

Its easy to make a text blink:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
$('#blinkText').toggle();
}, 300);
```

and in html, just give as follows:

```
<p id="blinkText">Text blinking</p>
```

Comment: I don't see any jquery tag.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have copied code from the accepted answer to [Blink not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647186/blink-not-working-in-chrome). The answer is wrong, however, and only tries to address WebKit browsers. The following code works in WebKit browsers, in modern Firefox, and in IE 10+ (I have set the parameters to simulate the way the classic `<blink>` worked):

```
@keyframes blink {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to   { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to   { opacity: 0; }
}
blink {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: blink;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

For a real cross-browser solution, you need JavaScript. It’s straighforward timed changes; see e.g. some answers to [Text blinking jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery).